# Improve gradle startup time with groovyserv or nailgun or what

Tags: performance, startup, gradle, nailgun

I'm trying to improve the startup time of Gradle.  The expererimental `--daemon` switch doesn't seem to really speed it up.  So I'm thinking to use some server process independent of gradle, and make gradle connect to it.  The options I found so far are

- [nailgun](http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/) to invoke java
- [GroovyServ](http://kobo.github.com/groovyserv/index.html) to invoke a groovy script

Since gradle is started by a shell script, it takes some tweaking.  My question is: has anyone used the above options to start gradle?  Or if you have successfully used another option, what's that?

Comment: Have you tried `--daemon` with the latest version (milestone-5)? I think they've added some performance improvements.

Comment: @rodion, I just tried it with milestone-5 -- the same looong 3 seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that your build is doing something at configuration time that it should be doing at execution time. With m5, `gradle build --profile` will give you an HMTL report showing where the time goes. Another way to see what's going on is `gradle build --info` or `gradle build --debug`.

Comment: thanks for the --profile switch tip.  Unfortunately, it just shows the very same problem: Startup: 2.8sec; Settings: 1.5sec; Loading: 0.3sec; Config: 0.8sec.  I'm trying the hello world project, so nothing fancy shows up when debugging.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't running with the daemon. Do you see this warning at the top of the build output? "Note: the Gradle build daemon is an experimental feature. As such, you may experience unexpected build failures. You may need to occasionally stop the daemon."

Comment: Ah, I see.  I thought I just have to run the daemon once, then gradle will check if it's running.  When I include the --daemon switch at each invocation, it speeds up startup time by 30% and all other phases a lot more significantly.  So the total time's improved by more than 50%.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: To enable the daemon permanently, add `-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true` to the `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable. In the future, this will become the default.